# Google Maps Directions URL Mobile App Bug

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a URL like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=37.3355814%252C-121.8884924&origin_place_id=ChIJ0cXEkLzMj4ARnhzl6coFKP4&destination=37.2491894%252C-121.8767183&destination_place_id=ChIJI4oCa94zjoARFMrewB8GJY8&waypoints=37.2757434%252C-121.8915153%7C37.2453031%252C-121.8898743&waypoint_place_ids=ChIJE_4nyIQzjoARWwYgEB86pHc%7CChIJBzy6ueIzjoAR4GYJKF4ugpc

It works perfectly on browsers (both PCs and mobile), but when you attempt to open it in the app (latest version iOS), the labels for each waypoint in the route are the encoded latitude and longitude, rather than the name from the place id, pictured below.

[image]

[image]

How can I maintain the names from the place ids when opening the link in the app?

Comment: Hello! Are you using Google Maps API/SDK for Android to do this? Or just purely the Google Maps App? If you're having issue with the app, and not with programming, feel free to send feedback to the app developers of Google Maps itself(https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1). As Stack Overflow is mainly for programming questions. I hope you understand. :'>

Comment: Hi! The app is just where the possible bug is relevant, my question is more about dynamically generating a directions URL (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) and if that's known to have an issue when opened in the app (vs in the browser).